# Flutter: Webview_flutter => open url from other page

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app with webview_flutter.
In thie Webview i opened/push a new Page.

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => openPage()),
      );
```

Now I want to Close/pop this page and change the URL in the WebView.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Closing is no problem, but how can I set a new URL from the "openPage" to the webview?
THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator.push()` returns a Future, which returns with `Navigator.pop()`

So you can do

```
onTap: () async {
    String myUrl = Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => openPage()),
    );
    setMyUrlFunction(myUrl);
}

///elsewhere...
Navigator.pop<String>(context, newUrl);
```

Also, `openPage` would be better to be a class, not a function.